# Putting a Non-Applet onto a website

Tags: java, html, applet

I have made a GUI in Java using State Based Game, as it extends StateBasedGame and not JApplet its not a true applet, I want to put it on a website and am unsure on how to do this, I have been told that the following code allows me to make this into an applet using html and not having to edit the Java code:

```
     <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" 
        archive="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" 
        codebase="." 
        width="640" height="480">

  <param name="al_title" value="Ham Blaster"> 
  <param name="al_main" value="org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameContainer"> 
  <param name="game" value="org.javagame.Game">

  <param name="al_jars" value="racegame.jar, lwjgl.jar, slick.jar"> 

  <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar"> 
  <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar"> 
  <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar"> 

  <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"> 
</applet>
```

I run that on html and get the following error message: org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader even though there is a AppletLoader class in my lwjgl.

If you can help me fix the above code then please tell me but if not possible please give me another method of putting my GUI onto a website.

EDIT1:

It may be worth mentioning, when I made my Java GUI, I had imported lwjgl and slick into eclipse, so I am assuming they are also in my racegame.jar file.

Comment: what's the full text of the error message? if it's a ClassNotFoundError, that means lwjgl_util_applet.jar is not accessible to the web page via the web server - with 'codebase="."', it's going to have to be able to be resolved at `http://yourserver:youport/lwjgl_util_applet.jar`

Comment: Yes it is a ClassNotFoundError, sorry I should have mentioned that in my post,I am trying to run it from my desktop at the moment so I just added /lwjgl_util_applet.jar after whatever was in the URL bar and it came up with the webpage not found.

Comment: I don't think Eclipse (or any other IDE) add's jars into jars by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader` needs to be in the archive specified in your `applet` tag, `lwjgl_util_applet.jar`. `lwjgl.jar` is just jar specified in a parameter which the `AppletLoader` interprets.

Comment: I have edited my code to show what I had changed as you hold told me to and tried the code but I still get the same error.

Comment: @mamtarani `archive` needs to point to the jar. As I type this, it's has the name of the class in it.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to Java and really dont know any html, the code was on a guide which I copied and modified so even most of that is hard for me to understand, could you please tell me how to point to  the jar. Also, do all my files need to be in a specific folder?

Comment: @mamtarani All the trusted library code will need to be in jars specified in the `archive` attribute. All you application code should be in jars specified by the relevant `param`. You shouldn't have code from both sides within the same jar.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My racecar.jar (which is all of my code for my GUI) was on my desktop, I now know from your post that it needs to now be moved into the javagame folder which is the param but I have two javagame folders for some reason, one in User/Workspace/Ham Blaster/Bin and the other in User/Workspace/Ham Blaster/Src, I placed it in both folders but I still get the same error. Also my param says org.javagame.Game, should it not be something like User/Workspace/Ham Blaster/Bin and the other in User/Workspace/Ham Blaster/...?

Comment: also is my archive supposed to be "org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" or is that wrong?

Comment: `archive` should be the path name to the library jar files relative to the location of the HTML file containing the applet tag. So if the HTML file is `/x/y/page.html` and the jar is in `/x/y/z/lib.jar` then you should have `archive="z/lib.jar"`. The same will go for the `al_jars` parameter, I assume. I'm not familiar with lwjgl, so I don't know what the `game` parameter is supposed to do.

Comment: my html code is being run from my desktop so when I load my html code I get the following in my URL: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/new%20%201.html, could you please tell me what would my x and y and z be from that? Also, yje Game param is my main class for my game, here is the guide I have been using http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **JWS** (Java Web Start). I don't really know a whole lot about JWS, but you can learn more about it here : https://www.google.com/search?q=java+web+start. It allows users to run or download java files from the web, so you can put java in your HTML. *Again, I don't know a whole lot about it*, I've only heard about it a couple of days ago (I had the same question).

Best Regards, TheSultan.